# Socket-io-client not connecting to socket-io, It does not show any error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets

#### This is my Server program

```
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')
const cors = require('cors')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || '5000'


const router = require('./router')

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

app.use(cors())
app.use(router)


io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User has connected.')

    socket.on('join', ({name,room}) => {
        console.log(name,room)
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("User has disconnected.")
    })
})


server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

#### and this is my Client side program

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import queryString from 'query-string'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

let socket

const Chat = ({ location }) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const [room, setRoom] = useState('')
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000'

    useEffect(() => {
        const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

        socket = io(ENDPOINT)

        setRoom(room)
        setName(name)
        

        socket.emit('join', {name, room})
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search])

    return (
        <div className='chat'>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

There's no error in the code, the react app seems to working fine , but I couldn't get the connection establishment .

I don't get the Connected console log or Client Connected console log and I don't know why!

Comment: You forgot to use `http`, use `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: I tried using http://localhost:5000 , still couldn't get the connection